# $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n+1}{n-i+2}(n-i+1)^{n}=1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How do I prove the equation in the title for all positive integers $n$?
I recently learned that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}=(1-1)^{n}=0$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}=(1+1)^{n}=2^{n}$ but can't get a grasp of ideas that help solve more complex binomial sums.